# What is the difference between Lazarus and Isaac

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I've unlocked Lazarus in Rebirth, and played with him, but except for having a lovely head of hair, he seems identical to Isaac. They have the same stats listed, and Laz starts with no extra items. Are there any other differences, or is it purely cosmetic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lazarus starts with different items than Isaac does.  Notably, he starts with an item that gives him an extra life (hence the name [Lazarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_of_Bethany)).

He also seems to start with a random pill... but unlike Isaac, Lazarus doesn't start with any Bombs.

Edit: I haven't gotten far enough to check this, but in the original game, Isaac would start with The Dice if you'd unlocked them... Lazarus likely doesn't.

Comment: Nice answer. I like the wiki reference about the name

Answer (score 3):

Isaac:

- Upon unlock, [**The D6**](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/The_D6)
- 1 bomb

Lazarus:

- On death respawns immediately in the same room with 1 red heart and gains [**Anemic**](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Anemic)
- A pill

Everything else, except look and unlocks that they get, seems to be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Lazarus:
Starting Items:
• A random pill
• 'Dead Cat' situation with 1 extra life
• A sweet hairdo

Isaac:
Starting Items:
• If unlocked, The D6
• A bomb